# Demonstrate the continuity of the derived function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in an interval I and there is an $a \in I$ such that for every $(x_n)$,$(y_n) \subset I$ with $\lim x_n=\lim y_n=a$ and $x_n \not= y_n$ implies that 
$$ \lim \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}=f'(a)$$
Prove that $f'$ is continuous in $a$.

- I've thought about trying to for every $(x_n)$ with $\lim x_n =a \Rightarrow \lim f'(x_n)=f'(a)$, but I fail to get the result.

Comment: Just a tip: no one says a function is "derivable".  We usually say "differentiable."

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f'$ is not continuous at $a$.  Then there exist $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \to a$ such that $|f'(x_n) - f'(a)| > \epsilon$.    By definition of derivative there exist $y_n$  with
$0 < |y_n - x_n| < |a - x_n|$ and $\left|\dfrac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} - f'(x_n)\right| < \epsilon/2$...